# Regex matches fine in tester but not in Python code

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to remove text between the strings "Criteria Details" and both "\n{Some number}\n" or "\nPage {Some number}\n". My code is below:

```
test = re.search(r'Criteria Details[\w\s\S]*?(\n[0-9]+\n|\nPAGE [0-9]+\n)', input_text)
print(test)
input_text = re.sub(r'Criteria Details[\w\s\S]*?(\n[0-9]+\n|\nPAGE [0-9]+\n)', ' ', input_text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

This works on regex101 for the string below, as I can see that the chunk between "Criteria Details" and "88" is detected, but the .search() in my code doesn't return anything, and nothing is replaced in .sub(). Am I missing something?

```
cyclobenzaprine oral tablet 10 mg, 5 mg,
7.5 mg

PA Criteria

Criteria Details

N/A

N/A

other

N/A

Exclusion
Criteria

Required
Medical
Information

Prescriber
Restrictions

Coverage
Duration

Other Criteria

Age Restrictions  Patients aged less than 65 years, approve. Patients aged 65 years and older,

End of the Contract Year

PA does NOT apply to patients less than 65 yrs of age. High Risk
Medications will be approved if ALL of the following are met: a. Patient
has an FDA-approved diagnosis or CMS-approved compendia accepted
indication for the requested high risk medication AND b.  the prescriber
has completed a risk assessment of the high risk medication for the patient
and has indicated that the benefits of the requested high risk medication
outweigh the risks for the patient AND c.Prescriber has documented that
s/he discussed risks and potential side effects of the medication with the
patient AND d. if patient is taking conconmitantly a muscle relaxant with
an opioid, the prescriber indicated that the benefits of the requested
combination therapy outweigh the risks for the patient.

Indications

All Medically-accepted Indications.

Off-Label Uses

N/A



88


Updated 06/2020
```

I would expect the output to be something like

```
cyclobenzaprine oral tablet 10 mg, 5 mg,
7.5 mg

PA Criteria



Updated 06/2020
```

Comment: Your regex is also working. See [**this**](https://onlinegdb.com/SyJFQbv68). I believe the probable thing that you're missing is `dotall` flag. One small query I have. Why are you searching the text first?

Comment: The text search was just to test out whether that pattern matched to anything. I plan on deleting it once the .sub is working.
I'm not sure if there's some weird character in the input text... I'm using pdfminer to extract the text out of this docuument: https://www.bcbst-medicare.com/docs/2020_Prior_Authorization.pdf
In that document, I'd like to remove all text between each Criteria Details section and the page number at the bottom. I elected to use Criteria Details as the starting tag, because it seems somewhat consistent between all documents (whereas PA Criteria might appear elsewhere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. When using Pdfminer to parse the PDF into text, there aren't actually newlines after the page number, but they get converted into newlines if I copy and paste the output to the regex website, or Stackoverflow. I ended up using \s instead of \n to detect the trailing spaces after the page numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You got it, just a silly mistake. Change your code to this

```
input_text = re.sub(r'Criteria Details[\w\s\S]*?(\n[0-9]+\n|\nPAGE [0-9]+\n)', ' ', input_text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(input_text)
```

Where you went wrong is

```
input_text = re.sub(r'Criteria Details[\w\s\S]*?(\n[0-9]+\n|\nPAGE [0-9]+\n)', ' ', input_text, flags=re.IGNORECASE) # This is the necessary replacement well done
test = re.search(r'Criteria Details[\w\s\S]*?(\n[0-9]+\n|\nPAGE [0-9]+\n)', input_text) # This extracts a pattern which will never be found because you already removed it
print(test) # The result of the previous line which would never be found
```

Hope this helps! We all have bad days

Comment: Sorry, the code to test it has the problem that you described above. I've changed it in the original post, but the .sub() itself doesn't seem to replace anything. In the edited code, "None" is printed out.

Comment: In that case can you update the snippet to better reflect your code, because I fixed the snippet 